# how to convert Thu Apr 06 14:30:00 IST 2017 for to this format 2017-07-05T16:50:22.490 in N1QL query

Tags: couchbase, sql++

how to convert "Thu Apr 06 14:30:00 IST 2017" for to this format 
"2017-07-05T16:50:22.490" in N1QL query

Comment: My couchbase version is 4.5.0

Comment: Can you provide us with more information? What have you tried? Is this value being passed as a parameter to the query? Is the value coming from Couchbase?

Comment: actually this "Thu Apr 06 14:30:00 IST 2017"  date format i am getting from other services i have use n1ql query for order by this date time format, But in n1ql query order by for this format is not working . i have to handle this from n1ql query end. n1ql query order by date do not works for this date format. that's i want to convert format to "2017-07-05T16:50:22.490" this format.

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting it into Couchbase, when you get the date from the other services, you have to first convert it into milliseconds. Once you do this then you can use the MILLIS_TO_STR date function to convert it to the format you want. The list of formats and the date function description is given in

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html

Comment: STR_TO_MILLIS('Thu Apr 06 14:30:00 IST 2017') returning null for this format.

Comment: Because the input format is incorrect. You need to do the conversion to milliseconds in your application itself, not in couchbase using n1ql. Only then can you use the N1QL functions. See allowed formats for N1QL date time functions in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

thanks kbinstance, it got resolved after converted to millsecond

```
String fulfillmenttime1 = "Thu Apr 06 14:30:01 IST 2017";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date1 = formatter.parse(fulfillmenttime1);
long longfulfillmenttime1 = date1.getTime();
```

After using Collections.sort  it got sorted . no need of using n1ql query.